# Prove $(p \rightarrow q) \land (r \rightarrow s) \implies ( \neg p \lor \neg r \lor q \lor s)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$$((p \rightarrow q) \land (r \rightarrow s))\rightarrow ((p\land r)\rightarrow (q\lor s))$$
I have some problem with formula:
$$(p \rightarrow q) \land (r \rightarrow s) $$
$$\equiv(\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg r \lor s)$$
$$\equiv(\neg p \land \neg r) \lor (\neg p \land s) \lor (q \land \neg r) \lor (q \land s)$$
I have to prove this implies:
$$(\neg p \lor \neg r \lor q \lor s)$$

The problem is that I don't know what to do to get this?

Wolfram says this is a tautology, but I don't know how to prove it
([Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Implies%28%28Implies%28p%2Cq%29%20and%20Implies%28r%2Cs%29%29%2CImplies%28%20%28p%20and%20r%29%2C%28q%20or%20s%29%29%29)).

Comment: If you want an equivalent form, it won't be of the last form.

Comment: They cannot be equivalent, since if $q, r,\lnot s$, then the first one is false, the second one is true.

Comment: I edited one thing $r$ should be $\neg r$ and wolfram tells that is tautology but how proof it?

Comment: the standard technique that always works for proving logical tautologies is using truth tables.

Comment: For 4 combinations? On exams i have 2 minutes on this

Comment: The tautology is that first one implies the second one, not that they are equivalent - you had to state it. I have edited it.

Comment: But how can i explain that this is tautology?

Answer (score 2):

In general, we have

$$(A\implies B)\iff(B\lor\lnot A)$$
and
$$(A\land B)\implies (A\lor B)$$

Applying the first of these, we get

$$((p\implies q)\land(r\implies s))\iff((q\lor\lnot p)\land(s\lor\lnot r))$$

Applying the second, we get

$$((q\lor\lnot p)\land(s\lor\lnot r))\implies((q\lor\lnot p)\lor(s\lor\lnot r))$$

Answer (score 2):

First note that
$$(p\land r)\rightarrow (q\lor s)$$
$$\equiv\neg (p \land r) \lor (q\lor s)$$
$$\equiv(\neg p \lor \neg r) \lor (q\lor s)$$
$$\equiv\neg p \lor \neg r\lor q\lor s$$
$$\equiv(\neg p \lor q)\lor(\neg r\lor s)$$
$$\equiv(p \rightarrow q)\lor(r\rightarrow s)$$
Therefore
$$((p \rightarrow q) \land (r \rightarrow s))\rightarrow ((p\land r)\rightarrow (q\lor s))$$
$$\equiv((p \rightarrow q) \land (r \rightarrow s))\rightarrow ((p \rightarrow q)\lor(r\rightarrow s))$$
$$\equiv\neg((p \rightarrow q) \land (r \rightarrow s))\lor ((p \rightarrow q)\lor(r\rightarrow s))$$
$$\equiv\neg(p \rightarrow q) \lor \neg(r \rightarrow s)\lor (p \rightarrow q)\lor(r\rightarrow s)$$
$$\equiv \mbox{tautology}$$